# How could map::erase know if the interval is valid?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

I'm writing a simple program which makes use of `std::map::erase`.
The program is fine, but there is something I do not understand.

If I pass to the `erase` function an interval in which the first iterator is beyond the second one, the function does not erase anything. And it is good.

On the other side, if I use `std::distance` with the first iterator beyond the second one this function "fails". I know that this is due to the nature of the map's iterator, and for example with `std::vector` there is not this problem.

But I do not understand how `map::erase` could know whether the interval is valid or not.

Comment: Please include some code in the form of a [MCVE] showing what what you're talking about.

Comment: @scohe001 I do not get how code could help understanding a generic problem, clearly explained.

Comment: In undefined behavior land, anything can happen.

Comment: Please don't add parts of the answer to your question. It's perfectly fine to have a misunderstanding in the question; that's probably why you had a question to ask in the first place :)

Comment: @cigien I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`std::distance`'s specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

> The behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by
> (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first.

There's an immaterial exception post-C++11 for random access iterators, but this does not apply to maps. This is undefined behavior, so a "failure", or even a crash is what you can get here.

`std::map`'s `erase()` method also seems to indicate that [this is undefined behavior, too](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

> 2. Removes the elements in the range [first; last), which must be a
>    valid range in *this.

The iterator values you're passing do not comprise a "valid range", hence this is undefined behavior too. Even though today that seems to do nothing, the resulting code is well within its rights if next week your code started crashing, because that's what "undefined behavior" means.

In conclusion, both `erase()` and `std::distance` result in undefined behavior in this situation.

Comment: My bad, I thought I was passing to `erase` an invalid interval. Instead it seems to be valid.

Comment: Nitpick: cppreference.com is not the or a specification. It is a community-curated Wiki that summarises the language rules defined by the real specification, The Standard.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't!

It just assumes the range is valid, and you'll only notice it isn't if it not being causes some unexpected symptom.

Whether that occurs or not is completely down to the specifics of the internal implementation and, quite possibly, chance. This is textbook undefined behaviour.

Comment: I was in fact passing a valid interval to `map::erase` but I wrongly thought it was not valid. My bad.

Comment: @vaeVictis Doesn't matter, this is still the right answer to the question you asked :P